# Comparing textbox value to database

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, textbox

HI !
I would like to compare values from a textbox with data from a table. I tried this code but i got the error that the input string was in the wrong format!
code:

```
string connectionString = 
    "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=save.mdb";

try
{

   database = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
   database.Open();
   string queryString = "SELECT zivila.naziv,users.user_name FROM (obroki_save "
       + " LEFT JOIN zivila ON zivila.ID=obroki_save.ID_zivila) "
       + " LEFT JOIN users ON users.ID=obroki_save.ID_uporabnika "
       + " WHERE users.ID='" +Convert.ToInt16(id.iDTextBox.Text)+"'"; 
   loadDataGrid(queryString);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
   return;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the textbox is all digits? Perhaps use int.TryParse instead.

Comment: Also read up on protecting yourself from Sql Injection! This is a classic example of Sql Injection potential!
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: Fair enough. Was just following up. Peeps new to this site often forget to follow up on asked questions.

Comment: What line throws the exception?

Comment: i just get the message box that the input string is in the wrong format

Comment: What is the type of users.ID?

Answer (score 0):

your connectionstring should look like this:

Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\mydatabase.mdb;User Id=admin;Password=;

Further information on connectionstrings you can find on connectionstrings.com

Answer (score 0):

when building your sql, you're trying to concatenate a string and an Int16 value.  try removing the Convert.ToInt16(), leaving just the string value of the textbox.

Comment: i get an error in the conditional expresion(that's what the program said)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your last line to

```
+ " WHERE users.ID=" +Convert.ToInt16(id.iDTextBox.Text);
```

basically removing the single quotes from around the Int16

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
string connectionString = 
    "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=save.mdb";

try
{
       Int16 id = Int16.Parse(id.iDTextBox.Text);

   database = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
   database.Open();
   string queryString = "SELECT zivila.naziv,users.user_name FROM (obroki_save "
       + " LEFT JOIN zivila ON zivila.ID=obroki_save.ID_zivila) "
       + " LEFT JOIN users ON users.ID=obroki_save.ID_uporabnika "
       + " WHERE users.ID=" + id.ToString(); 
   loadDataGrid(queryString);
       database.Close();
}
catch (FormatException fex)
{
   MessageBox.Show(fex.Message);
   return;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
   return;
}
```

This way you would intercept bad data and protect yourself from Sql Injection.

Also, don't forget to Close your connection, or read up on the using the [using keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02(VS.80).aspx).

Also try to run the query with a hardcoded id value in your sql editor to make sure it works:

```
SELECT zivila.naziv,users.user_name 
FROM (obroki_save AS os LEFT JOIN zivila AS z ON z.ID=os.ID_zivila) 
LEFT JOIN users ON users.ID=obroki_save.ID_uporabnika 
WHERE users.ID=16
```

Answer (score 0):

if your ID field is an int, you shouldn't be putting ' around it.

so change

```
 + " WHERE users.ID='" +Convert.ToInt16(id.iDTextBox.Text)+"'";
```

to

```
 + " WHERE users.ID=" +Convert.ToInt16(id.iDTextBox.Text);
```